# SSRS SumLookup Returns Zero

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I'm building a report in SSRS and using the sumlookup function and report code from http://salvoz.com/blog/2013/05/27/sum-result-of-ssrs-lookupset-function/ . I have used it and it has worked well in the past but now no matter what I do the function returns 0.

Here's the equation:

=Code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!Program_ID.Value, Fields!Program_Id.Value, Fields!Weight.Value,  "FirstDateRangeDataSet"))

The equation should return a value of 407,058 .

Comment: It looks like it should be working. Have you checked your data to make sure there are no issues? You can create a **calculated field** on the dataset and test with `=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!Weight.Value) OR NOT ISNUMERIC(Fields!Weight.Value), 0, Fields!Weight.Value)`. If using the new field works, the issue was your data.

Comment: Try to run the `Lookupset()`, see if it fetches data!

Comment: You need to look at your data and datasets to identify why your code shows 0.