# Why are date values not showing in the output of my SSRS report using LookupSet?

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS, I need to use the LookupSet function to display all "No-Show Dates," related to a certain client Id, in a single cell (to limit the Id to showing in only 1 row).  LookupSet appears to be working in the report for other fields.  But for the date field in question, it displays nothing except the set/series divider (a comma).

This is what I'm getting (see the top row of data, far right):
[report output]

[image]

The tables are grouped on the field "Id".

Notice the Id in a LookupSet function displays properly.
The bottom-left and the bottom-right tables show, respectively, tests using:

- no Group except the standard "(Details)" group)
- a test to ensure the date is displaying, using this test, similar to the one suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826243/ssrs-sumlookup-returns-zero): `=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!NoShowDate.Value)Or Not IsDate(Fields!NoShowDate.Value),0,Fields!NoShowDate.Value)`

Here is the expression I'm using to try to display these No-Show Dates:

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!Id.Value, Fields!Id.Value, Fields!OrderStatusMessageDateKey.Value, "DataSet1"), ", ")
```

And here is the actual data going into that report run (pulled from SQL Server): [SQL Server data]

[image]

I tried adding formatting as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60925957/formatting-ssrs-output-with-multiple-dates), but it generated no changes.

---

I tried making a dummy dataset using this below query text, to stand in for the actual dataset's production data ... but it resulted in the same types of blank output:

```
SELECT
    1 AS Id
    , CAST('2023-06-29' AS date) AS NoShowDate
UNION
SELECT
    1 AS Id
    , CAST('2023-06-19' AS date) AS NoShowDate
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's hard to tell what the problem is without some more data. First thing I noticed though was that in one code snippet you use `OrderStatusMessageDateKey` and in another `NoShowDate`, maybe one is from you test data but it's hard to tell. What happens if you dump `DataSet1` to a table, do you see the dates? Finally, is all the data coming from a single dataset or is there a main dataset and another dataset with the dates in? Reproduce with the smallest amount of data you can, post the report design here if you are still stuck.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  And ... you are right!  I used `NoShowDate` as only the test version of `OrderStatusMessageDateKey` -- but I didn't realize that I had actually changed the field name at some point.  So it was not displaying the date values because it was looking for `OrderStatusMessageDateKey` which no longer exists.  Using `NoShowDate` displays the dates as expected.

Comment: No problem, we've all been code-blind at some point. I'll vote to close the question as it was effectively a typo, or you can delete the question yourself.